# Extend startapp in Django 2 to pre-wire App templates, statics, urls etc

Tags: django

How can I extend `manage.py startapp` command to pre-create various folders and pre-wire templates, statics, urls etc?

For example, if I do `manage.py startapp myapp` within project `myproj`, the following will be automatically done:

1. Automatic folder creation for myapp\templates\myapp, myapp\static\myapp\css, myapp\static\myapp\js
2. File myapp\urls.py automatically added, with standard content as Django project creation
3. base.html automatically added in app template folder

etc.

Those are examples which may grow more, need to know where to start looking into all these.

Comment: Why dont you write your own management commant. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management

Comment: looking for something simpler for project initialization. accepted answer suffices, and also i found out about cookiecutter tool .. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an folder say `sampleapp`, this can contain all the structure you want and you can you `python manage.py startapp <appname> --template=path_to/sampleapp` . This should work

Comment: Can the file content use the <app_name> or <project_name> variable somehow? Standard skeleton has file apps.py whose content is 'class MyappConfig(AppConfig): name = 'myapp'. How can the file be dynamically generated based on app name?

Comment: You can use variable `{{app_name}}` in your `sampleapp` template